# Mysql Query not giving all results of one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

table 1:

```
genreartismap:
id - pk
artistid
genreid
val - this column has default value 1
```

table 2:

```
genre:
id - pk
name
```

Now what I am trying to do is get the distinct genre.names against a list of genreartismap.artistid.

For Ex:

I have genreartismap.artistid's = 7,4,6,9,10,8

I have genreartismap.genreid's associated against this list artists = 4,5,6

I am trying to get the following result:

```
genreid genrename   count
4       Electronica 2
5       Punk        4
6       EDM         3
```

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT  `genreartistmap`.genreid AS id,  `genre`.name AS name, SUM(  `genreartistmap`.val ) AS val
FROM  `genreartistmap` 
LEFT JOIN  `genre` ON  `genreartistmap`.artistid
IN ( ids ) 
GROUP BY genreid
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing the `join` on the wrong column.  I would expect `genreartistmap.genreid = genre.id`:

```
SELECT gam.genreid AS id,  g.name AS name, SUM(gam.val ) AS val
FROM  `genreartistmap` gam JOIN 
      `genre` g
       ON  gam.genreid = g.id
GROUP BY gam.genreid;
```

I also think an `inner join` is sufficient for this query and introduce table aliases to simplify it.

Comment: Yes I realised that mistake. so now I am doing SELECT gam.genreid AS id,  g.name AS name, SUM(gam.val ) AS val
FROM  `genreartistmap` gam JOIN 
      `genre` g
       ON  gam.genreid = g.id
WHERE `genreartistmap`.artistid
IN ( ids ) 
GROUP BY gam.genreid;
 reason being that I want this over only particular id's of arists.